# Components with fontweight css rule in style definition results in a typescript error: No overload matches this definition error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-sketchapp

I'm setting up react-sketchapp using the [basic-setup-typescript](https://github.com/airbnb/react-sketchapp/tree/master/examples/basic-setup-typescript) example.
The example application is not compiling due to an type error related to styling.
It looks like Text and View components with the `fontweight` css rule in style definition results in a typescript error: `No overload matches this definition error`

Considering this code snippet from [my-command.tsx](https://github.com/airbnb/react-sketchapp/blob/master/examples/basic-setup-typescript/src/my-command.tsx)

```
const Swatch = ({ name, hex }: SwatchProps) => (
  <View
    name={`Swatch ${name}`}
    style={{
      height: 96,
      width: 96,
      margin: 4,
      backgroundColor: hex,
      padding: 8,
    }}
  >
    <Text name="Swatch Name" style={{ color: textColor(hex), fontWeight: 'bold' }}>
      {name}
    </Text>
    <Text name="Swatch Hex" style={{ color: textColor(hex) }}>
      {hex}
    </Text>
  </View>
);
```

You can see that the style definition for the `View` component has multiple rules while the `Text` component has only two.  This example results in  the error above `error TS2769: No overload matches this call.`

Removing `fontWeight` from the `Text` component allows the code to compile and render the example.

```
<Text name="Swatch Name" style={{ color: textColor(hex) }}>
  {name}
</Text>
```

Moving `fontWeight` to the `View` component results in the typescript error again.

```
  <View
    name={`Swatch ${name}`}
    style={{
      height: 96,
      width: 96,
      margin: 4,
      backgroundColor: hex,
      padding: 8,
      fontWeight: 'bold' <--- added
    }}
  >
```

It looks like there is a problem with the type definitions, but I'm having difficulty tracking it down.  I did find a types file (`src/types`) in which `TextStyle` extends `ViewStyle` type definition and does include fontWeight as optional:

```
export type TextStyle = ViewStyle & {
  ...
  fontWeight?: string;
  ...
```

A couple of questions here:

1. Does the error I'm seeing indicate a problem in the type definition
   or something else?
2. What are my options for fixing this?